# References request: Ramanujan's tau function.

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms

References request: Ramanujan's tau function.
Let $\Delta(z)=q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^n)^{24}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tau(n)q^n$, $q=e^{2\pi i z}$.
How can one show the following using representation theory?
$$
\tau(n)=\sum_S \frac{(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(a-e)(b-c)(b-d)(b-e)(c-d)(c-e)(d-e)}{1!2!3!4!}, 
$$

where $S$ is the set of ordered tuples $(a,b,c,d,e)\in \mathbb{Z}^5 $ with

$$(a,b,c,d,e) \equiv (1,2,3,4,5) \pmod 5 $$ $$ a+b+c+d+e=0 $$  $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=10n.$$
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi LJR. The formatting on your question was very funky because of the size of the displayed expressions, so I made some fairly large changes to get everything to fit. I hope this is acceptable.

Comment: @Potato, thank you very much.

Comment: Dear LJR, If you're still interested in this, could you give some context for this formula.  I was wondering if it is some kind of $\theta$ series or something along those lines, maybe coming out of a comparison with an automorphic form on another group, but without any context, it's hard to know; I may be completely off-base.  Maybe you have a different kind of representation theory (something more combinatorial) in mind?  Regards,

Comment: @Matt, Dear Matt, thank you very much. I found this formula in a book (which is not in English). I searched on Google and found that there is a related question on Mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9716/whats-the-status-of-the-following-relationship-between-ramanujans-tau-funct Regards,

Comment: The formula is mentioned in [Freeman Dyson's 1972 Gibbs lecture titled "Missed opportunities"](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1972-78-05/S0002-9904-1972-12971-9/S0002-9904-1972-12971-9.pdf) with references to MacDonald's work on affine root systems.