# Freeman Dyson's identity for the modular discriminant $\Delta$

Tags: quadratic-forms, modular-forms, theta-functions

In his 'Introduction to Modular Forms', Don Zagier states the Freeman Dyson's identity :

$$\Delta(\tau)=\sum_{\substack{
   (x_1,\ldots,x_5)\in \mathbb{Z}^5 \\
   x_1+\cdots+x_5=0 \\
   x_i \equiv i \pmod 5
  }} \left(\frac{1}{288}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq 5}(x_i-x_j)\right)q^{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2)/10}$$
with $q:=e^{2i\pi \tau}$. I would be very interested in a proof of that result.

Thanks everyone !

Comment: [Related (though more restrictive and still unanswered) question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606379)

Comment: This one is perhaps easier and in the same spirit: $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)^8 = \sum_{\substack{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{Z}^3\\x_1+x_2+x_3=0\\x_i\equiv i\pmod{3}}}\left(\frac{1}{0!\,1!\,2!}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq 3}(x_j-x_i)\right)q^{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-2)/6}$$

Comment: For a bit of context: The formula for $\Delta$ appears in chapter4, section C, *Theta series*, pg. 247 of Zagier's *Introduction to modular forms*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it took me more than 4 years (already!) to find a complete answer. This formula corresponds to the Macdonald identity of $\mathfrak{sl}_5$. There is a similar formula for $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ for odd positive $n$, and the one in @ccorn's comment corresponds to $n=3$. The proof of Macdonald, however, is purely combinatorial and does not explain why there is modularity here. Using Wronskian of $\theta$ functions (motivated by the appearance Vandermonde determinant in coefficients), one can reprove the formula. See this recent [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10191).